# Java Error: "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Player

Tags: java, int, bluej, selection-sort

I'm having trouble with my code and can't figure out how to remedy the error I'm receiving. I'm getting an error "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Player" in the line containing team[index] = temp; Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm really new to Java, and this is my first time attempting to use selection sort. I have tried looking around and searching but still haven't figured out this error after 3 days banging my head on the desk with it. Thanks in advance!

```
public static void selectionSort(Player[] team, int team_size)
{
    int index;
    int smallestIndex;
    int minIndex;
    int temp;

    for (index = 0; index < team_size - 1; index++)
    {
        smallestIndex = index;

        for (minIndex = index + 1; minIndex < team_size; minIndex++)
            if(team[minIndex].getNumber() < team[smallestIndex].getNumber())
                smallestIndex = minIndex;
        temp = team[smallestIndex].getNumber();
        team[smallestIndex] = team[index];
        team[index] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is just what the error means. The parameter `team` is an array of `Player` objects. `temp` is just an int. So when you try to set `team[index]`, which is a Player object, it cant do that.

Are you just trying to swap the two Players in the sort? Maybe temp should be a `Player`

```
Player temp;
```

Then for the swap

```
temp = team[smallestIndex]; //returns the actual Player instance rather than getNumber();
team[smallestIndex] = team[index];
team[index] = temp;
```

Also, you probably don't want to pass in `team_size` as you can get the length of your Player array by using `team.length`. This way you don't have to rely on passing the correct length in every time. Your for loop would look like this

```
for (index = 0; index < team.length; index++)
```

Comment: This completely solved my issue. I hadn't realized that temp being an int would be the problem. Thank you for helping clarify the error for me, and how to resolve it!

Comment: No problem! If it did solve your issue, its customary to click the green check mark on the left side of the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
team[index] = temp;
```

`temp` is an `int`, as defined by your method. `team` is an array of `Player` objects, thus `team[index]` is a `Player`. You are trying to assign an `int` to a `Player` on this line.

Note that you set the value of `temp` here:

```
temp = team[smallestIndex].getNumber();
```

I find your code a little hard to read, as I don't really know the context, but you should make sure that you always assign `team[someIndex]` a `Player` object.

Comment: Thank you as well for helping to clarify the error and why I was getting it.